# Expressao dentro da ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um problema com expressão no angular

Assim não funciona !checked || !checked2

```
<body ng-app="">
    <label>
        Click me to toggle: 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"> 
        &nbsp; 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked2">
    </label>
    <br/>
    <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked || !checked2">Button</button>
</body>
```

Assim funciona checked || checked2

```
<body ng-app="">
    <label>
        Click me to toggle: 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"> 
        &nbsp; 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked2">
    </label>
    <br/>
    <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked || !checked2">Button</button>
</body>
```

preciso de 2 checkboxs que a medida que seleciono um dos dois, certo campo será habilitado, seria isso um bug?

Comment: Essa pergunta não se encaixa na tag regex

Comment: Quando um checkbox está marcado, ele automaticamente se torna **TRUE**, a condição " !checked || !checked2 " não vai funcionar porque ele diz: *"Só funcione se algum dos checkbox estiverem False (desmarcados)"*

Comment: Eu não entendi onde você está identificando possível Bug aí, as condições estão corretas. O Ng-Disable só funciona se a condição dentro dele ter output TRUE

Comment: Não sei se encaixa como bug, mas desta maneira funcionou
!(controle || controle2)

A ideia aqui é que, com checkbox marcado o retorno seria true, negando isso o retorno seria false, negando o ng-disabled do campo

lembrando que testei a expressão !controle || !controle2 dentro de um ng-checked e funcionou, não precisei alterar para  !(controle || controle2), apenas dentro do ng-disabled que não funcionou.

Comment: Vou responder abaixo para você entender melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Como mencionado pelo usuário [Jackson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91775/jackson):

> Quando um checkbox está marcado, ele automaticamente se torna TRUE

Do jeito que você fez ela só funcionará **caso um dos dois checkbox estiverem desmarcados**, pois você usou o token de negação `!` antes de `controle` e `controle2`.
O que acho que você quer fazer é colocar por fora da parte `(controle || controle2)`, resultando em `!(controle || controle2)` ou voltar a usar `ng-checked` como você mencionou no comentário.

Answer (score 2):

Isso está certo. Vou fazer em booleans para você entender.
Output do NG-Disable desabilita o elemento quando o output dele é **True**.

Na sua dúvida de **!(controle1 || controle2)** seria **!( true || true )**

Essa expressão inicia com os dois controles FALSE, então...
**!(false || false)** => **true**

Se você marca um ou dois, ele irá desabilitar o botão, porque...
**!(true || true)** => **false**  
**!(false || true)** => **false**

> É igual matemática, execute o que há dentro do parenteses, para depois executar o que está fora.

Comment: boa explicação +1!

Comment: Vlw cara percebi msm,Confundi na lógica msm.

!controle1 || !controle2 assim apenas se os dois estivessem como true, para saída ser false, desabilitando o disabled.

!controle1 || !controle2   <>  !(controle1 || controle2)

Answer (score 2):

A diretiva [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), se receber um valor `false`, vai liberar o botão, se receber um valor `true` vai bloquear o botão, então, a lógica sua pode ser analisada por uma função, que ao final deve negar o resultado, ***exemplo***:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = false;
  $scope.checked2 = false;
  $scope.btnStatus = function()
  {
    return !($scope.checked || $scope.checked2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>
        Click me to toggle: 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"> 
        &nbsp; 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked2">
    </label>
  <br/>
  <button ng-model="button" 
    ng-disabled="btnStatus()">Button</button>
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)</sub>